# How do I call a custom init on a view controller instantiated from a Storyboard scene in interface builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

If I am using interface builder to manage storyboards for my app, how can I call a custom `init` selector when view / view controller instances are created?

For example if  I have a view controller in a Storyboard scene, and its **Custom Class** is a `UIViewController` subclass, with a custom initialiser, such as `initWithMediaType:`, which takes an `NSUInteger` as an argument, how can I specify in Interface Builder that `initWithMediaType:`should be called, passing in a given argument?

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756504/viewcontroller-custom-init-method-with-storyboard

Comment: You don't.  You need to perform initialisation in `viewDidLoad` or in `prepareForSegue:` in the presenting view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify in Interface Builder, declare `mediaType` as a property in your `UIViewController` subclass, and use 'User Defined Runtime Attributes'.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @rintaro. Do you know when these attributes get set? I'm assuming it's after `initWithNibName:bundle:` is called, but is it before or after `prepareForSegue:sender:`?

Comment: I confirmed that the initialiser is not `initWithNibName:bundle:`, but `initWithCoder:` as @rdelmar mentioned in another answer. Anyway, it's after `initWithCoder:`, but before `prepareForeSegue:sender:`.

Answer (score 3):

When you init your `UIViewController` from `storyboard` The system actually calls `- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder`.

So, When you want to make your own init, you should override `- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder` method in your custom `UIViewController`.

For your specific question, you can consider use `prepareForSegue:` and set your mediaType in it:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```

Hope that help.

Comment: No, initWithCoder: is called for objects made in a storyboard, not initWithNibName:bundle: